# Content Resolver query PHOTO_URI from multiple numbers

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I want to make a single query that will return the ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.PHOTO_URI for multiple numbers

Now i use this:

```
    Cursor contactLookupCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, UriContactNumber),
            new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.PHOTO_URI}, null, null, null);

    while (contactLookupCursor.moveToNext()) {
        photoUri =  contactLookupCursor.getString(contactLookupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.PHOTO_URI));
    }
```

I want to pas more numbers to Uri.withAppendedPath. Can i do that?